# 2 values for a single input box and storing the 2nd value in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am using two values for 1 input box, when user selects multiple boxes the values will be submitted to submit_checkbox.php. I want to save the 2nd value i.e value after "|" sign in the php form. How can I do it ? My code is as follows :-

```
<form name='checkbox' method="post" action="submit_checkbox.php">

    <b><h3>Select option</h3></b>
    <input type="hidden" name="qq1[]" value="null">
                <input type="checkbox" name="qq1[]" value="ABC|DEF"> A<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="qq1[]" value="GHI|IJK"> B<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="qq1[]" value="LMN|PQR"> C<br>
 <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" >
    </form>
```

And in "submit_checkbox.php" the code is as follows :-

```
    <?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'root1';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    mysql_select_db("my_db") or die(mysql_error());
    list($value1,$value2)=explode('|',$_POST['qq1']);
    $values=implode(',', $value2);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO print_chk VALUES ('$values')";    
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Success";
    }
    ?>
```

However, I am unable to put the 2nd value in the sql table "print_chk".

Comment: There is no "two values", what you've got is just invalid HTML

Comment: To be clearer, you have to do `value="ABC|DEF"`, now you have an attribute, followed by invalid characters

Comment: @adeneo Yes, you're right, it is value="ABC|DEF". I am editing my code. It was a typo error.

Comment: @adeneo :- If I use $values=implode(',', $_POST['qq1']);     

I am able to insert the checkbox input in the mysql table, however I need only the 2nd value.

Comment: I'm guessing `$_POST['qq1']` is an array

Comment: And it should be noted that `mysql_*` methods are deprecated and insecure

Comment: What is this line `$values=implode(',', $value2);` for? The `$value2` contains a single string. And what's your `print_chk` table's schema? Does it contain more fields? Modify your code: `$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ) or die(print($sql).'<br>'.mysql_error());` to see if there is an error, and post here the output.

Comment: Moreover, you have syntax error in your HTML (`<label class="q" for="qq1" </label>`) and you select your mysql_db twice.

Comment: @Fenistil $values=implode(',', $value2); is for storing the 2nd values of each checkbox i.e if user selects option A and option C $values will store DEF,PQR.  print_chk is a mysql table having only 1 attribute "name" "varchar" "20". It will store "DEF,PQR".

Comment: It doesn't male much difference. However I edited the code, removed label and selected db only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$_POST['qq1']` is an array, so you have to explode every element of it and then make the string from this. Try something like this, it works for me:

```
//Get the second part
function GetSecond($v) {
    if ($v != 'null') {
        $a = explode('|',$v);
        return $a[1];
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}

//Since $_POST['qq1'] is an array, get the second part of each item
$v = array_map('GetSecond',$_POST['qq1']);

//Filter out the empty strings
$v = array_filter($v);

//Implode the list
$values = implode(',',$v);

//Insert to DB
$sql = 'INSERT INTO print_chk VALUES ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($values).'")';
```